# The segments $[0,\inf(X,Y)],[\inf(X,Y),\sup(X,Y)],[\sup(X,Y),1]$ form a triangle

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Two points $X$ and $Y$ are randomly chosen on $[0,1]$, i.e. $X$ and $Y$ are two independent random variables with the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. What is the probability that the segments $[0,\inf(X,Y)],[\inf(X,Y),\sup(X,Y)],[\sup(X,Y),1]$ form a triangle?

Can anyone give me a hint to solve this question?

Comment: It's the "every segment is smaller that the sum of the other two" thing, is it not?

Comment: Then, i.e., $[0,\inf(X,Y)] + [\inf(X,Y),sup(X,Y)] > [sup(X,Y),1]$ ? How am i gonna reach the probability equation from there? By writing each equaility like i did?

Comment: The condition can be simplified: the length of each segment does not exceed $0.5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

The segments form a triangle iff:

$$X<0.5<Y<X+0.5\text{ or }Y<0.5<X<Y+0.5$$

Comment: Can we end up with $0.25$ ?

Comment: Yes, I think that is the correct answer: $2\int_{0}^{0.5}\int_{0.5}^{x+0.5}dydx=0.25$